# Simple react setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to do this simple React app with the state.

It is throwing an error when I type something into the input: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Input() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Enter input.")
    const pushInputValue = (event) => setInputValue(event.this.value)
    return (
        <div className="Input">
            <h3>Enter input.</h3>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={inputValue}
                onChange={pushInputValue}
            ></input>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Input
```

Comment: when you type something into the input, it triggered the change event of your input, which calls your `pushInputValue`. the function is passed a event object, where you use `event.target.value` to access the input value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix `event.this.value` to `event.target.value`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Input() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Enter input.");
    const pushInputValue = (event) => setInputValue(event.target.value);
    return (
        <div className="Input">
            <h3>Enter input.</h3>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={inputValue}
                onChange={pushInputValue}
            ></input>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Input;
```